# What IP range can I use setting up a new interface on my router for a subnet?

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing, subnet

What IP range can I use setting up a new interface on my router for a subnet?

I want to set up a new subnet on my router using an additional physical interface I have. Right now my LAN is using the default gateway of 192.168.0.1/24.

I'm a little confused as to whether or not I'm limited by my network and ISP as to whether or not I can use any CIDR and ip range for subnets on my network.

Specifically I want to set up a DMZ on my network, currently my LAN is set up as:

LAN interface: 192.168.0.1/24 using IPs 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.254

Can I set up my new interface as:

DMZ interface:192.168.254.1/24 using IPs 192.168.254.1-192.168.254.254

Do I have unlimited freedom on my network to use any set up I want? I will probably stick to using the set up I mentioned but I have also considered switching to a 10.0.0.x network, am I even free to do that if I want to?

Comment: Do you have multiple public IPs or any any other kind of special WAN configuration?

Comment: No. I'm talking about my internal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any IPs you want. You just won't be able to access them anymore if they're actual internet IPs. That said there are some [common ranges used for private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces).

Most common for home routers is probably `192.168.0.0/16`, possibly with a longer subnet mask like `/24`. Depending on your model of router you may or may not be able to change this. Also handling multiple subnets can be dependent on your router or more specifically the firmware and the options it exposes to you. You might have to look into alternatives like [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) or [DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/) which would allow you do to pretty much anything configuration wise.

The other common private IP ranges from [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) would be:

```
10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

The advantage of those ranges is that they should not be internet routed. So traffic that could leave your network would be discarded. As always there is a chance your ISP does something strange as well but he shouldn't.

A simplified example for your setup might look like this:

```
Client 1: 192.168.1.10/24
Client 2: 192.168.2.10/24
Router Phyiscal Interface 1: 192.168.1.1/24
Router Physical Interface 2: 192.168.1.1/24

Routing Table for Router 1:
Dest.             Interface
192.168.1.0/24    eth0
192.168.2.0/24    eth1
0.0.0.0           wan0
```

Each client would reside in it's own subnet and only if the router would be configured to route between those and its default route the clients would be able to talk to each other/the internet.

Comment: Great, that's helpful. I use pfsense which is a very configurable router and should be able to change anything I need to. I guess what I want to do is change it to a /16 subnet so that I'm able to add additional subnets in the third dotted quad.

Comment: Not really. If you change it to `/16` it would be one network with more useable adresses. If you want to use actual subnets keep the `/24` and configure an IP of one subnet for the interfaces which should have them. You will need to enable it to route betweent those networks if you want your clients to be able to communicate with each other.